# Conditional solution for system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I have a linear equation system `Q.m = t`, with `m` unkown and where `Q` has dimensions `{(n-1)²,n²}`, `t` has dimensions `{(n-1)²}` and `m` dimensions `{n²}`.  I'm trying to find a way to find a (possible) solution `m1` such that `Norm[Partition[m1,n]]` is less or equal to 1. My idea goes something like this:

Somehow optimizing using the solution given by `LinearSolve[Q,t]` and `NullSpace[Q]`. I got some help with the code from a friend, he gave this suggestion:

```
ns = NullSpace[Q];
vars = Array[p, {Length@ns}];
sol = Partition[m + vars.ns, n];
NumericMatrixOnly[f_][args_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := f[args]
AbsoluteTiming[
res = FindMinimum[Max[NumericMatrixOnly[Norm][sol], 1], vars];]
m1 = sol /. Last@res;
```

This solution isn't as fast or accurate as I would want, in what other ways could I optimize this? I could do it with alternating projections, but I wanted to see if Mathematica have any nice built-in methods.

Comment: You can get a minimal l2 vector solution via `m2 = LeastSquares[Q, t]`. This might often suffice for your stated purpose. When it odes not it could give a good set of starting values for the `FindMinimum` approach. I suspect that latter has difficulty in that it is dealing with a matrix norm, for which it has no analytic expression for derivatives and the like. All the same, using a least-squares solution as a first guess should work well because there are inequalities relating that to Frobenius norm of the partitioned matrix, and that in turn to the 2-norm of that matrix.